# Problems with compiling darknet under ANACONDA

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have installed opencv under ANACONDA, start ANACONDA promt navigation to darknet folder, make make operation, but prompt

> g++ -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -DCUDNN  -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -fopenmp -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -DCUDNN -c ./src/image_opencv.cpp -o obj/image_opencv.o
>   Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
>   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'opencv' found
>   ./src/image_opencv.cpp:5:30: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: 没有那个文件或目录
>   compilation terminated.
>   Makefile:86: recipe for target 'obj/image_opencv.o' failed
>   make: *** [obj/image_opencv.o] Error 1